# JavaScript String split: fixed-width vs. delimited performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, performance, split

I am building a string to be parsed into an array by JavaScript.  I can make it delimited or I can make the fields fixed-width.

I have only tested on Windows with Firefox and Chrome, so please run the test from other OSes and browsers. My two test results are clear: `String.prototype.split()` is the winner by a large margin.

Is my fixed-width code not efficient enough, or is the built-in string split function simply superior? Is there a way to code it so that the fixed-width parsing triumphs?  If this was C/C++, the fixed-width code, written properly, would be the clear winner. But I know JavaScript is an entirely different beast.

Comment: I'd suggest putting your code inside a `function` to better hint the optimiser. But it's still [just a microbenchmark](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).

Comment: @Bergi - so you're saying the question has no real answer unless I test it within the context of my real-world code in a single run with the largest plausible dataset? The total real-world performance difference might truly be negligible, but I wanted to see. This jsperf uses a small, but real-world dataset, so it seemed like a plausibly useful test.  I just put stuff inside functions and the results are essentially the same.

Comment: I was thinking [of something like this](https://jsperf.com/string-split-fixed/2), which also fixes the bug where `i < data.length` should have been `i < array.length` - this increases perf by a factor of 16 :-) Still a huge difference though.

Comment: @Bergi - in Firefox your bug fix makes `fixed(data)` the winner, so kudos for that.  But Firefox is so much slower than Chrome overall on this. Here is another sub-split variation that also shows `slice()` to be faster than `split()`. This one is not so much a microbenchmark because I really do loop over the array of strings and split each one: https://jsperf.com/ss-split-vs-slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a built-in JavaScript function. Expect it to be highly optimized for the particular JS engine and be written not in JavaScript but in C++.

It should thus not come a surprise that you can't match its performance with pure JavaScript code.

String operations like splitting a delimited string are inherently memory-bound. Hence, knowing the location of delimiters doesn't really help much, since the entire string still needs to be traversed at least once (to copy the delimited fragments). Fixed-position splitting *might* be faster for strings that exceed D-cache size, but your string is just 13KB long, so traversing it multiple times isn't going to matter.

Comment: "*the entire string still needs to be traversed at least once (to copy the delimited fragments)*" - that depends on the string representation, which might only create string objects referencing the same underlying buffer, with different offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I wasn't necessarily surprised, but I wanted to know.  If you look at the comments to my original question you'll see some variation in this.  In Firefox on Windows the revised fixed-width javascript code runs faster, but way slower than in Chrome.